# Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource when connecting to Google SQL

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

This is somewhat odd.

Within the last week I have been able to connect to a test database that i created in GCP.  I didn't download credentials and I didn't change anything with cred configuration.  I simply updated the database source url in my application.properties.

- I can still connect locally without an issue.

This is the application.properties section that's relevant:

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================
# Set here configurations for the database connection
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gametest
#gcp
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://35.222.131.172:3306/gametest
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Today, I try to connect and receive this exception

```
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:342) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2188) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2221) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2016) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at
```

I've checked:
-I can connect to the Google DB using the Cloud terminal

-The DB is up and running

-No firewalls etc are in place

-Nothin dramatic has happened to the app (added storage methods, nothing else)

- I tried whitelisting my IP by using the terminal before connecting
- I checked the cloud logs, it is up, running and waiting for connections.
- I've not been spamming connections so there shouldn't be an issue there.
- Double checked pom.xml to make sure JDBC still there
- Ran a compare against both the properties and pom to check for dodgy stuff.

Following on from some SO posts I find someone suggest that this is the correct way instead:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/<DBNAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<MYDABINSTANCENAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
```

I've added that in and am now receiving another exception which point to API credentials.

```
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to obtain credentials to communicate with the Cloud SQL API
    at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SslSocketFactory$ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.create(SslSocketFactory.java:545) ~[mysql-socket-factory-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SslSocketFactory.getInstance(SslSocketFactory.java:138) ~[mysql-socket-factory-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory.connect(SocketFactory.java:47) ~[mysql-socket-factory-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:301) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2188) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2221) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:95) ~[google-api-client-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:213) ~[google-api-client-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:191) ~[google-api-client-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SslSocketFactory$ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.create(SslSocketFactory.java:543) ~[mysql-socket-factory-1.0.0.jar:na]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

So, my question is pretty much - anyone know why it worked before and why ti isn't now?  *DO* I need the credentials file for this to work and if so, how did I connect so easily last time?  And, of those two that I posted, can anyone tell me what is the best method for defining the datasource without having to jump through  plethora of hoops for connecting to the db please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would delete this but it may help someone else.

My IP is not static, on the connections page of the SQL instance is an authorised public IP.  This was my home IP but it had since changed.

sigh.